# Laravel AUTH with Guard Show Logged in User credentials

Tags: php, laravel

I'm Having Problem with my multi Auth Laravel application. I am trying to login my admin user with a guard which is admin,   `{{ auth()->user()->username }}` this is the code that im using to show the logged in user username it works fine but when i put it on my admin dashboard it gives me error

This is the error i got

> "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\centralsocialv2.4\resources\views\admindashboard.blade.php)"

This is my `Admin.php`

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';

    protected $table = 'admins';


    protected $fillable = [
      'username', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

This is what handles my Admin Login on `AdminController.php`

```
public function adminlogin(Request $request)
{

       // Validation 
       $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
  ]);



  $username = $request->input('username');
  $password = $request->input('password');

  if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password]))
  {
   return view('admindashboard');;
  }
   return ('Nope');

}
```

My Dashboard view where admin redirects if logged in

```
<h1> Hi there   {{ Auth::user()->name }}   you are logged in as Admin 
</h1> 

@if (!Auth::guard('admin')->check())
no admin
@else
yes admin
@endif

<a href="{{ route('userlogout') }}" > Log out </a>
```

Something wrong with my Code? Thank you guys!

Comment: you are using the wrong attribute use `username ` instead of name

Comment: Hi this is my phpmyadmin https://imgur.com/CeXp1va

Comment: i leave the name null cuase im just testing it but i have username registerd

Comment: have you craeted a user...??

Comment: yes i did https://imgur.com/gbfx2r0

Comment: use this code `{{dd(Auth::user())}}` and show me the output

Comment: it says null :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code

```
<h1> Hi there   {{ Auth::guard('admin')->user()->username  }}   you are logged in as Admin
```

Comment: the other one worked change the name to username then it works but im not getting the username form my database

Comment: Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::gaurd does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\centralsocialv2.4\resources\views\admindashboard.blade.php) gives me this error

Comment: add this at the top of your controller `use Auth;` and what vertion of laravel you are using

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta you have mistake in your spelling it is `guard` not `gaurd`

Comment: Yayy it worked hmm i noticed you miss typed the guard i think that would work the first try because i already have [ use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; ]

Comment: Thank you Again you saved me All the love from PH <3

Answer (score 0):

As your column name is `username` change `Auth::user()->name` to `Auth::user()->username`

```
<h1> Hi there   {{ Auth::user()->username }}   you are logged in as Admin
```

Or you can also use `auth()`

```
<h1> Hi there   {{ auth()->user()->username }}   you are logged in as Admin
```

Comment: Still got some errors :/ I miss typed i am using username cuase i leave the name null check this out https://imgur.com/gbfx2r0

Comment: i tried @ Shaielndra Gupta  {{dd(Auth::user())}} and it says null

Comment: @Cedrick what is the error you see now after changing name with username?

Comment: Trying to get property 'username' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\centralsocialv2.4\resources\views\admindashboard.blade.php)

Comment: Great that your issue solved ! I think you mistakenly accepted my answer. Please accept the answer which provided you the solution. :)